# laravel 8 ->add comment and replies for post with polymorphic relation

Tags: laravel, api, polymorphism

i'm building API with laravel 8 and want to add comments and replies for posts with polymorphic relation (because i have `posts` and `analysis` that they have comments.)

so i created my tables. my post table :

```
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

            $table->string('title');
            $table->longText('body');
            $table->longText('picture');
            $table->string('study_time');
            $table->integer('likes')->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('status')->nullable()->comment('status is 1 when a post is active and it is 0 otherwise.')->nullable();
            $table->text('tags')->nullable();


            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

and my comments table :

```
        Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->integer('commentable_id');
            $table->string('commentable_type');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable(); //nullable for comments , with value for replies
            $table->string('name' , 45);
            $table->string('email');
            $table->longText('comment');
            $table->integer('like')->nullable();
            $table->integer('dislike')->nullable();

            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
```

as you see , i don't need to authentication for comments.
so my post model has this relation:

```
 public function comments()
    {

        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable' )->whereNull('parent_id');
    }
```

and the comment model :

```
   public function commentable(){

       return $this->morphTo();
       
   }

   public function replies()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id');
   }
```

and then i create a CommentController for CRUD comments and in my store method i put this code for add a new comment :

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $comment = new Comment;

        $comment->name = $request->name;
        $comment->email = $request->email;
        $comment->comment = $request->comment;

        $post = Post::find($request->post_id);

        $post->comments()->save($comment);

        return response()->json($comment);

    }
```

when i send request in postman , i get this error : `Error: Call to a member function comments() on null`

i know its for `post_id` but i don't know how to change it , i'm beginner and i don't know so much about polymorphism in laravel , just used this link for create comments :
https://appdividend.com/2018/06/20/create-comment-nesting-in-laravel/

can you please tell me where is my mistake? thank you so much

edited :

```
$data = $request->all();
        $validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'name'=>'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'comment'=>'required',
            'post_id'=>'required|exists:posts,id'
        ]);

        $post = Post::find($request->post_id);


        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors(), 'Validation Error']);
        }

        $post->comments()->save($data);

        return response()->json($post);
```

why gives me this error ? : `TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, array given`

Comment: request->post_id is null, you should validate it

Comment: thank you .. i though it's a problem .. and can you help me for validating it?

Comment: i edited my question and put my code for validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you just have to add a validation rule for post id, it should be 'required' and '[exist](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#specifying-a-custom-column-name)':

```
 $validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'name'=>'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'comment'=>'required',
            'post_id' => 'required|exists:posts,id'
        ]);
// make sure that post table name is 'posts' and the id column name  is 'id',
// or changed according to your db ..

  $post = Post::find($request->post_id);
```

now you guarentee that the `$request->post_id` will be valid input.

now you can save that comment:

```
$comment= new Comment($data);
 $post->comments()->save($comment);
```

Comment: ok but i have an error for saving it .. can you check it again please?

Comment: yes, you have to pass a comment object to save method, not array, I have edited my answer